# How to force logout somebody from ASP.NET using Cookies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know what is the way to force logout somebody when I ban them?
I am using this way of login process

```
private async Task SignInWithRoleAsync(string email, string userRoleName)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRoleName));

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
    }
```

I couldn't find an answer for that question so far.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it depends how you decide to ban a user and how to check it. In application business logic you must decide when is the proper moment to check user status. After that, you can do something like this

- .Net Framework:

Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

- .Net Core:
  [AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signoutasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

I would use middleware if it were me. it's not possible access to auth cookie when banning. Bcs auth cookies is store in client session database.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var bannedUser = new string[] { "foo@foo.com" };

            if (bannedUser.Contains(httpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(ClaimTypes.Email)))
            {
                await httpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }

            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
        }
```

You can find detailed information about middleware here. https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/aspnet-core-middleware